# Logic Issue - NSObject class - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 2 questions.

1.) I am creating a `NSObject` class, and i am having the following code in it. (`ASIHTTPRequest` `POST`).
The name of the `NSObject` class is called, `SendToServer`. I call the class as follows;

```
SendToServer *sv = [[SendToServer alloc]];
sv.grabURLInTheBackground ;
NSLog(@"This line is executed ");
```

The following is the code that is in the `SendToServer` `NSObject` class.

```
- (void)grabURLInTheBackground
{
   if (![self queue]) {
      [self setQueue:[[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease]];
   }

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
   [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
   [[self queue] addOperation:request]; //queue is an NSOperationQueue
}

- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSString *response = [request responseString];
}

- (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

The problem is that, the code executes the line `sv.grabURLInTheBackground ;` and before it executes the `requestDone` or `requestWentWrong` methods, it executes the NSLog (`NSLog(@"This line is executed ");` )

What i want my program to do is to complete all the operations in the `SendToServer` `NSObject` class and then Execute the NSLog (In a sequence).

First execute `sv.grabURLInTheBackground ;` once all the activities in that method/class is over, then return to the code and execute the other line which is `NSLog(@"This line is executed ");` .

2.) I need to return a String when the `requestDone` method is executed. How do i modify the code to do so;

```
- (NSString * )requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
}
```

but how do i edit  `[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];`, for the above code ?

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**EDIT**

I am doing this for user login. Upon button click i will be calling the `grabURLInTheBackground` method from the `NSObject` class. And the viewcontroller needs to know if the user login was successful or failed.

```
SendToServer *sv = [[SendToServer alloc]];
[sv grabURLInTheBackground] ;
NSLog(@"User login SUcess or failed %@", [sv userloginSucessOrFail]);
```

For example say `[sv userloginSucessOrFail]` returns if the user login was success or failed.

What hapence here, is that after `[sv grabURLInTheBackground]` is called, it directly goes and executes the `NSLog(@"User login SUcess or failed %@", [sv userloginSucessOrFail]);` line of code.

What i want is, i need to find a way to let my ViewCOntroller know if the user login was a Success or failure.

Comment: The name of your method, `grabURLInTheBackground`, implies that the work will be done in the background, which is the exact opposite of what you're describing.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a workaround to prevent this. It is ASIHttpRequest that i am using. Also i have added the 2nd question below, I need to know how to return NSString from the method `requestDone`

Answer (score 0):

First: call init on your object.

Second: grabURLInTheBackground is a method not a property. It should by called with square brackets

So you code becomes:

```
SendToServer *sv = [[SendToServer alloc] init];
[sv grabURLInTheBackground];
NSLog(@"This line is executed ");
```

To accomplish point 1) you need to make a synchronous request

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [request error];
  if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
  }
```

The problem is that if this code is executed on the main thread is blocking (not good)...

For the second point. You can't.

EDIT:
What you have to do is something like the following steps:

- Before calling grabURLInTheBackground you have to notify the user that a request is pending.. like putting an UIActivityIndicator, or disabling the UI,...
- when you receive the callback then update the UI: hide the activity indicator, re-enable the UI... or if the request failed, notify the user.

Comment: So you say this is a bad idea (to use `synchrounous`) ? `MVC` suggest to have controller functions separately, so that is why i am keeping the `ASI code` in a different class. So if it's unable to return a String then does it suggest that it doesn't support `MVC`?

Comment: No. MVC is independent from sync/async calls. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to accomplish it will be easier to find a solution...

Comment: I have edited my question adding more detail. Please have a look. Help